# Open/Change IE9 Tabs Using SendMessage/PostMessage

Tags: c#, tabs, internet-explorer-9, sendmessage, postmessage

I'm trying basically SendKey's to IE9 to change tabs. I have 3 tabs so I'd need to Send keys Ctrl+1, Ctrl+2, Ctrl+3 and also Ctrl+T to open a new tab.

I start by adding the import dlls and constants

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg,
 IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg,
 IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
```

I get the instance of Internet Explorer by opening a new process.

```
Process p = Process.Start("iexplorer.exe");
```

Use the process handle to PostMessage to IE9 instance

```
IntPtr handle = p.MainWindowHandle; //p.Handle (doesn't work either)
//Change to Tab2 using PostMessage

PostMessage(handle, WM_KEYDOWN, ((IntPtr)Keys.LControlKey), (IntPtr)0);
PostMessage(handle, WM_KEYDOWN, ((IntPtr)Keys.D2), (IntPtr)0);
PostMessage(handle, WM_KEYUP, ((IntPtr)Keys.D2), (IntPtr)0);
PostMessage(handle, WM_KEYUP, ((IntPtr)Keys.LControlKey), (IntPtr)0);
```

No response. I've also tried using SendMessage to no avail as well.

Am I doing anything obviously wrong?

Comment: p.Handle will be the process handle, not a window handle.

Comment: Also, IE9 launches a new process per tab.  So the .MainWindowHandle is pretty meaningless in your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `SendKeys("^1");`

as seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)

Comment: Boo thanks for the response. I'm familiar with SendKeys but I don't want to use it because it requires focus. The MainWindowHandle is the proper handle as I'm trying to send keystroke to the main containing Window.

Comment: the container window might not be the one that processes keyboard input.  I'd be surprised if it was.

Comment: I'm just going to mark this as this obvously wrong answer because I need the points. Either this can't be done or people don't want to share how it's done.